# HATEOAS Links on Spring Framework @pathvariable Map argument fails

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas

I am writing a ReST API using Spring-mvc and Spring hateoas framework. I am trying to create a 'self' Link to a method that has @pathvariable Map as parameter. I am tying to allow multiple pathvariables (and it may grow in future) for the method and within the method I am trying to resolve a separate path based on the presence or absence of a variable.It all works fine till I try to create a self link.

I am getting an exception

There was an unexpected error

> type=Internal Server Error, status=500). No converter found capable of
>   converting from type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
>   java.util.Map] to type
>   [java.lang.String]

Here is my Method

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/subs","/masterclient/{masterclient}/subs"}, 
    method = RequestMethod.GET)

   public List<Jobs>  getJobList(
         @PathVariable  Map<String, String> pathVariables,
         @RequestParam(value="count", required = false) int count) 
   {

      if (pathVariables.containsKey("masterclient")) 
      {
         System.out.println("Master Client = " +
                         pathVariables.get("masterclient"));
      } 
      else 
      {
         System.out.println("No Master Client");
      }



      //Add a Link to the self here.
      List list = new ArrayList<Jobs>();
           list.add(linkTo(methodOn(ControllerJobs.class).getJobList(pathVariables, count)).withSelfRel());

      return list;
   }
```

The Exception stack trace is below

> 2016-10-24 15:39:48.821 ERROR 12068 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   .a.c.c.C.[.[.[.c.v.a.[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [/com.causeway.vixen.api] threw exception [Request processing failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
>   java.util.Map] to type
>   [java.lang.String]] with root cause
>
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
>   java.util.Map] to type
>   [java.lang.String]    at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:313)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195)
>   ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.AnnotatedParametersParameterAccessor$BoundMethodParameter.asString(AnnotatedParametersParameterAccessor.java:172)
>   ~[spring-hateoas-0.20.0.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.java:143)
>   ~[spring-hateoas-0.20.0.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilder.java:172)
>   ~[spring-hateoas-0.20.0.RELEASE.jar:na]   at
>   com.causeway.vixen.api.application.ControllerJobs.getJobList(ControllerJobs.java:153)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_102]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_102]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [na:1.8.0_102]

Comment: Please format your exception as code (curly braces icon in the editor)

Comment: I just saw an interesting link that confirms that java.utils.Optional from java8 has not been implemented yet . Here is the link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/373